# Symlink error when installing modules with npm

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

I'm trying to install nodemon globally but I'm getting the following error:

```
npm ERR! Darwin 15.4.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "nodemon"
npm ERR! node v5.10.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.3
npm ERR! path ../lib/node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -1
npm ERR! syscall symlink

npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../lib/node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/nodemon'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../lib/node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/nodemon']
npm ERR!   errno: -1,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../lib/node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js',
npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/local/bin/nodemon' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Juanjo/Developer/budget-app/npm-debug.log
```

I'm new to node (literally the first thing I tried to run after installing it) but I don't think I'm supposed to use sudo to install modules, so perhaps there's something wrong with permissions or something, I just haven't been able to find out what it is. Any help is really appreciated.

This is on OS X 10.11. I already tried both

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

and

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local
```

But still no luck.

Comment: If you've used the official Node.js installer, then, yes, you do need `sudo` to install _global_ packages; consider a [user-level installation](https://github.com/mklement0/n-install) instead.

Answer (score 9):

Symlink Issues could really be an issue.

For me, the shortcut was to turn it off by running the installation wihout symlink options like this below:

```sh
npm install --no-bin-links
```